# Add column with image and textblock in checkbox input type bot framework c#

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards

I'm working on a adaptive card in bot framework v3 using c#. I want to have input choice fields and each choice option is having a image and a text box. so is it possible to achieve it and if yes how can we achieve that, as below

[image]

Tried code:

```
var choiceinput = new AdaptiveChoiceSetInput(); 
var Choices = new List<AdaptiveChoice>(); 
card.Body.Add(choiceinput); 
Choices.Add();
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: i have a body, then i have created choiceInput and pushed that to body, later created choices. Now in that choices i want to push my column set as it contains the required structure, but its not allowing to, it just allow title in string.

```var choiceinput = new AdaptiveChoiceSetInput();
                                    var Choices = new List<AdaptiveChoice>();
                                    card.Body.Add(choiceinput);
                                    Choices.Add(); ```

Comment: Please edit formatted code into your question instead of trying to post it in comments

Comment: Added the code in question

Comment: Is Tim's answer acceptable?

Comment: Actually he suggested json template approach, i'm looking for a way to achieve this using c#, as i have made complete adaptive card using c#

Comment: Why are you using the v3 SDK? Would you accept an answer that uses the v4 SDK? What channel are you using?

Comment: No, i was trying to create a group chat, but got update from MS Teams developer Team support that Group chat using a bot is not supported currently

Comment: Well @MayureshJaiswal you don't have to use templating, you can build the card purely in c#. Its just as i said you can't use choiceSets alone but need to do a lot more to get your card working like that. In C# that'd be really complicated id say. Thats why i suggested templating :)

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to achieve is not possible using ChoiceSets alone.
ChoiceSets are pretty much key-value pairs.

You can however use a combination of input.toggle and ColumnSets like here:

```
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "ColumnSet",
        "columns": [
            {
                "width": "10px",
                "type": "Column",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "Input.Toggle"
                    }
                ],
                "verticalContentAlignment": "Center"
            },
            {
                "width": "45px",
                "type": "Column",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "Image",
                        "style": "Person",
                        "url": "https://graph.facebook.com/1989019881113809/picture?type=large",
                        "width": "45px"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "width": "stretch",
                "type": "Column",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "text": "Jack Maa",
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "weight": "Bolder"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Advisor - Scale Prediction & Control",
                        "type": "TextBlock"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "ColumnSet",
        "columns": [
            {
                "width": "10px",
                "type": "Column",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "Input.Toggle"
                    }
                ],
                "verticalContentAlignment": "Center"
            },
            {
                "width": "45px",
                "type": "Column",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "Image",
                        "style": "Person",
                        "url": "https://graph.facebook.com/1989019881113809/picture?type=large",
                        "width": "45px"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "width": "stretch",
                "type": "Column",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "text": "Mayuresh Jaiswal",
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "weight": "Bolder"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Water Treatment Advisor",
                        "type": "TextBlock"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1000.0"
```

}

Final card would look like this:

[image]

I'd really suggest having a look at templating however. Building as complex cards is really not great in c# directly and templating makes things for you a lot easier in scenarios like that more than any.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/